# Limit of the series of functions $f_n$

Tags: real-analysis, pointwise-convergence, sequence-of-function

$$f_n(x)=
\begin{cases}
 1&\text{if }\, x\geq 1/n\\
 n|x|&\text{if }\, x< 1/n.
\end{cases}$$
We want to find the pointwise limit of this function. I think the answer should be $f(x)=1\thinspace \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$. But the answer given is 
$$f_n(x)=
\begin{cases}
 1&\text{if }\, x\neq 0\\
 0&\text{if }\, x=0.
\end{cases}$$

This is confusing me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But clearly $f_n(0)=0$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$. Therefore, $f(0)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(0)=0$.